# Transfer domain from godaddy to another registrar and (somewhat) maintain privacy?

Tags: godaddy, domain-registrar, transfer, privacy

Does anyone know if its possible in any ways to do this?

Transfer a private domain (via domainsbyproxy) registered at godaddy to another registrar.

While I know moving a domain from godaddy requires the privacy to be disabled, what we were  thinking of doing is the following:

a) Update the whois info inside domains by proxy to a 3rd party. Most likely a law firm who would in essnece become our 'custodian'.

b) Wait 60 days (?)

c) Disable domain privacy. Now the law firms details would become public.

d) Conduct the domain transfer.

e) Take ownership of the domain at the new registrar.

Does something like this sound possible?

Does anyone know any other way to handle this?

Thanks.

Comment: For the benefit of others in the future, it might now be possible to transfer from GoDaddy and still maintain privacy. The thing that probably makes a difference is if the privacy service of the previous (current at the time) registrar forwards email sent to the account in the **domain registration** then it might be possible to do a transfer from them without disabling privacy.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds fine, you can change your whois to the firm so that if whois.sc or any other whois scraper archives it your name and details will be hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I would get contact your new host and ask them directly.
I'd personally recommend calling [hover](http://hover.com) and get them to do it for you. They're really quite good at transfers from godaddy and I've moved several of my domains to them.

Disclaimer: I am in no way related to this company (hover), and do not receive any referral gains. I just love how they will do the whole thing for you for no extra change.